# Is it possible to highlight some states of US and some states of Canada in GeoChart?

Tags: google-visualization

[Region 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhKUp.jpg)

[Region 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dHY6.jpg)

I am trying to add map on a location page and I want to select some states from US and Canada in different regions when user hovers on a specific part of the map. Basically a map of North and South America(Brazil and Argentina) with different regions.

In the following code I attempted to highlight 2 US states and 1 Canada state. But I get "Requested map does not exist" error when I try to highlight states on a continent.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['geochart'],
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['State', 'Offices'],
            ['New Jersey', 2],
            ['Alabama', 3],
            ['Toronto', 1]
        ]);

        var options = {
            region: '019', // Americas Continent
            colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']
            },
            backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
            datalessRegionColor: 'gray',
            defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
            resolution: 'provinces'

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
    
    </html>
```

Is it possible to do so? How can I achieve something like the image attached?

I would really appreciate your time and help. Thank you!

Comment: according to the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options) -- `resolution: 'provinces'` -- can only be used with _country_ regions, whereas `'019'` is a _continent_ region...

Comment: Yeah. I saw that too. I was wondering if there is some workaround to this problem. Thank you for your time.